# Rewrite all links on reverse proxied page

Tags: javascript, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm reverse proxying to a IP restricted page like this:

```
server {
    server_name mypage.com;
    listen 80 ;

    location / {
       proxy_pass https://sandbox.otherpage.com/;
       proxy_bind $server_addr;
    }
}
```

This works good but all links on the page (including AJAX calls) links to https://sandbox.otherpage.com/

I am not sure whether I do something wrong or the the other web application I'm proxying to links to the absolute page.

How can I rewrite these links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sub filters](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) to do what you want

```
location / {
  proxy_pass https://sandbox.otherpage.com/;
  proxy_bind $server_addr;
  sub_filter "https://sandbox.otherpage.com/" "https://myserver.com/";
  sub_filter_once off;
  sub_filter_types *;
}
```

You can get rid of the `sub_filter_types` if you only need to match html files.

Also you might need to add `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""`.

Comment: This is amazing but sadly it doesn't work. Even replacing a simple string on the website does not work.
My nginx is configured with the mandatory `--with-http_sub_module`. I checked it via `nginx -V`.
Do you have an idea what could be the cause?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem myself. I had to add the following options: `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""` and `sub_filter_types *`

Comment: It depends on which files you needed to do the replacement, I assumed only html, will update the answer