# Use Nginx as a HTTP proxy for Chrome and other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, proxy

I need to access a IP restricted website. Since the IPs of my coworkers any my own one changes all the time I would like to use one of my root servers running Nginx as a Proxy in Chrome and Firefox.

Yet I don't know how to set up Nginx for that kind of usage. Googling is also difficult because the term proxy is used in a lot of different contexts.

C**an I configure Nginx to act as a HTTP proxy to that page, if yes, how do I set it up?**

Note: I can't use it as a reverse proxy to the page. It does work but all links on the page point to the original URL which I can't fix easily (at least I don't know how).

Comment: `nginx` works fine as a reverse proxy, but is not really the solution for a forward proxy. I haven't used it, but squid is often suggested.

Comment: I will have a look at it. This is the problem I have with reverse-proxying to that page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980982/rewrite-all-links-on-reverse-proxied-page

Comment: @Hedge why not tor ?

Comment: @IAmBatman The target page It is restricted to a single IP address.

Comment: @Hedge you are using which OS (operating system) ?